# Youtube, vimeo, hulu, vube in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, xamarin

Try to create feed which show shared video from **youtube**, **vimeo**, **hulu** and **vube**.

For this, I create custom view which has thumbnail by default and after user tap thumbnail replaced by UIWebView with url to shared video.
After page loaded, I try to start play video using Media API and method play.
That works good for vimeo, but does not work for youtube, unfortunately i did not check with hulu and vube.

Maybe someone have have workable solution, or some suggestion how that can be done?

Comment: Your question lacks more information about what exactly does not work. Please ask specific questions instead of general solutions.

Comment: If specific question, can I start play youtube video using Media API after this video was loaded in UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to display a youtube video inside your application is by using the YouTube Helper Library, developed by Google, which provides a subclass of UIWebView that you can use.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) you'll find every information you need.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I need not only youtube, that's why I would like to find general solution, if it exists